# Little command line video grabber

Tags: python, beginner, python-3.x, beautifulsoup

I made a little Python3 script to grab video clips from a website for viewing off-line later and would like your critique, advice, tips & tricks and/or learning resources to create better code. (Project on [GitHub](https://github.com/markhamden/phgrab))

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
''' phgrab.py: clip downloader. '''

import os
import sys
import argparse
import urllib.request
import bs4


def reporthook(blocknum, blocksize, totalsize):
    ''' Define the reporthook for url-retrieval
    (displays info while grabbing). '''
    readsofar = blocknum * blocksize
    if totalsize > 0:
        percent = readsofar * 1e2 / totalsize
        display = "\r%*d / %d %5.0f%%" % (
            len(str(totalsize)), readsofar, totalsize, percent)
        sys.stdout.write(display)
        if readsofar >= totalsize:
            sys.stdout.write("\n")
    else:   # total size unknown
        sys.stderr.write("read %d\n" % (readsofar,))


PARSER = argparse.ArgumentParser(
    description="a commandline clip downloader.")
PARSER.add_argument('clipcode', nargs='+',
                    help="a ten-digit clipcode.")
PARSER.add_argument('-p', '--proxy',
                    help="A http proxy to use; e.g. http://localhost:8000")

PROXY = PARSER.parse_args().proxy
CLIPCODES = PARSER.parse_args().clipcode

if PROXY:
    print("Grabbing through http proxy: %s\n" % PROXY)
    os.environ['http_proxy'] = PROXY

for i in CLIPCODES:
    if not i.isdigit() or not len(i) == 10:
        sys.exit(
            "'\033[1m%s\033[0m' is not a valid ten-digit clipcode," % i,
            "please check your input and try again.")

for i in CLIPCODES:
    soup = bs4.BeautifulSoup(
        urllib.request.urlopen("http://somesite.com/%s" % i))
    title = soup.find("h1", class_="video-title").string
    href = soup.find("a", class_="download button")['href']
    print("Grabbing \033[1m%s\033[0m:" % i)
    local_filename, headers = urllib.request.urlretrieve(
        href, '%s - %s.mp4' % (i, title), reporthook)
    print("\033[1m", local_filename, "Done\033[0m")
```

Comment: I felt that the actual used site was not very relevant to your code question, so I decided to edit your post and remove the actual site. This code will probably work for more than one site.

Comment: Hi @simon-andré-forsberg, I wrote this script for this site and did not (yet) consider usability for other sites and, at first glance, have not found other use-cases. I'll check it out, Thanks!

Comment: Either way, you should be careful with what links you spread.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

#### A bug

This just won't work:

> ```
> sys.exit(
>     "'\033[1m%s\033[0m' is not a valid ten-digit clipcode," % i,
>     "please check your input and try again.")
> ```

`sys.exit` takes a single integer parameter to use as the status code of the program, so that callers can check if the program terminated normally or failed.
I suppose you wanted to print instead and then `sys.exit(1)`.

#### Move all code to methods

Don't keep code in the global namespace.
A good practice is to move everything to methods,
and call them from inside a `if __name__ == "__main__":` guard, like this:

```
def parse_args():
    # arg parser code

def main():
    args = parse_args()
    proxy = args.proxy
    clipcodes = args.clipcode

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

This way it will be possible to import the module into a larger app later.
Another advantage is that it doesn't pollute the global namespace,
which could lead to obscure bugs.

#### Use `print()` if you want to print

Printing with `sys.stdout.write` is very unusual and tedious.
Using `print()` is more common and simple.
If you don't want to print a newline, use the `end=''` flag, for example:

```
print(message, end='')
```

#### Naming

`i` is really a very poor name in this loop:

> ```
> for i in CLIPCODES:
>     if not i.isdigit() or not len(i) == 10:
>         # ...
> ```

It would be better to use something more descriptive, for example `clipcode`.

Another thing here, `not len(i) == 10` is a very odd way of writing `len(i) != 10`.

---

It's very unusual to see ALL_CAPS for variable names that are not global constants.
For example `DEFAULT_PROXY_PORT = 8080` would make a fine global constant,
but these look really odd:

> ```
> PARSER = argparse.ArgumentParser(...)
> CLIPCODES = PARSER.parse_args().clipcode
> ```

Comment: Hi @janos, many thanks for your help & advice! I'll implement & update (and read some more about the aforementioned topics) ASAP.